# Number of ways to form distinctive number given sum of digits

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, combinations

We are given sum of digits *M* and maximum number of decimal places *N*.
We have to find the count of number that can be formed such the the sum of digits is *M* and the consecutive digit of the number should ***not*** be less than the previous digit for example:-

- If *M* = 5 and *N* = 2
  Possible numbers that can be formed are:- 05,14,23
  Hence count=3
- If *M* = 3 and *N* = 3
  Possible numbers that can be formed are:- 003,012,111
  Hence count=3
- If *M* = 6 and *N* = 3
  Possible numbers that can be formed are:- 006,015,024,033,114,123,222
  Hence count=7

Comment: This is the number of partitions of $M$ into at most $N$ parts.  Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts  Wait, maybe not.  Are the digits restricted to being $\le9?$  Then what I said would not be correct.  It would be the number of partitions on $M$ in at most $N$ parts not exceeding $9$.

Comment: @packetpacket No, in a partition the summands are ordered.

Comment: @packetpacket No, 5-8-5 and 5-5-8 are the same [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))  You are thinking of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))

Comment: @saulspatz My bad, I understand now.